# mongoose only saves "_id" and "_v"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, post, mongoose

i have a problem to save data to database,when i post the data, its only saves _id and _v only

.here my api

```js
const createPatient = (req, res, next) => {
  const patient = new Patient();

  name = req.body.name;
  email = req.body.email;
  hashed_password = req.body.hashed_password;
  ID = req.body.ID;
  address = req.body.address;
  KK_number = req.body.KK_number;
  occupation = req.body.occupation;
  photo = req.body.photo;

  

  patient.save( (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: err,
      });
    }
    console.log(patient);
    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Successfully signed up!',
    });
    console.log(result);
  });
};
```

anyone know whats wrong with my code?

Comment: You don't use `name`, etc variables anywhere.

Comment: Yes.. you're true.. thanks.. but i found i better way. Thats deleting all the name and etc. And change `const patient = new Patient(req.body)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are not creating the patient object. While you are creating variables to hold the patient details, you are not adding them to the patient object.

This should work.

```
const createPatient = (req, res, next) => {
  const patient = new Patient({
  name : req.body.name;
  email : req.body.email;
  hashed_password : req.body.hashed_password;
  ID : req.body.ID;
  address : req.body.address;
  KK_number : req.body.KK_number;
  occupation : req.body.occupation;
  photo : req.body.photo;
});

  patient.save( (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: err,
      });
    }
    console.log(patient);
    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'Successfully signed up!',
    });
    console.log(result);
  });
};
```

Comment: You need colons in the object initializer rather than equals signs.

Comment: @Paul I overlooked that. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: Cool. Perhaps you could mark my answer as the right answer if there are no other concerns? :)